# Update Field based on another table's Field values

Tags: mysql

i want to update a filed named "outofdate"(type date : 2015-01-14 10:03:11 ) based on another filed name "lastmodification" .
i want to add 10 days to "outofdate" field where :outofdate < NOW() (actual date)

My code is not working:

```
Update *
`mytable` set outofdate = lastmodification + 84500*10
WHERE  outofdate < NOW( ) LIMIT 0,100
```

thx in advance!

Comment: Why did you put the * sign after the update operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Update *`?  That is not valid syntax.  I think the rest is basically ok:

```
Update mytable
    set outofdate = lastmodification + interval 10 day;
    WHERE outofdate < NOW( )
    LIMIT 0, 100;
```

Note that the number of seconds in a day is not 84,500.  Also, for date/time data  types, use `date_add()` or `interval` addition.

Comment: UPDATE `mytable` SET outofdate = DATE_ADD( lastmodification, INTERVAL 10 DAY ) WHERE outofdate < NOW ( )