# Update Fields based on another Fields value (date fields)

Tags: sql-server

Aim: Update Column C 'New Date' based on finding a value in Column B 'valuefield'. Column C 'New Date' will be a date from Column A 'Current Date'

I have used the below in the past but I am now asked for a third argument. I have search and tried "YYYY-MM-DD" at the end but can't quite make the leap to the answer.

Software:I am using SQL in Server Management(2012)

```
UPDATE TBLTABLE
SET  NewDate= (CurrentDate + DATEADD(DAY,730)) 
WHERE VALUEFIELD = 'XYZ'
```

Notes: Updating with a known value I know but I don't 'know' the value of each 'Current Date' field and this also ensures I don't have to run distinct date.

Looked at:
[Update Field based on another table's Field values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28395557/update-field-based-on-another-tables-field-values)

[Update a column based on a field from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853640/update-a-column-based-on-a-field-from-another-table?lq=1)

[SQL UPDATE SET one column to be equal to a value in a related table referenced by a different column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707371/sql-update-set-one-column-to-be-equal-to-a-value-in-a-related-table-referenced-b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It realy depends what is in  CurrentDate. I guess its a datetime.

```
   UPDATE TBLTABLE
    SET  NewDate=  DATEADD(DAY,730,CurrentDate )
    WHERE VALUEFIELD = 'XYZ'
```